# How to use JavaScript in Selenium RC with Java

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-rc

I have the following function in user-extensions.js:

```
Selenium.prototype.doTypeRepeated = function(locator, text) {
    // All locator-strategies are automatically handled by "findElement"
    var element = this.page().findElement(locator);

    // Create the text to type
    var valueToType = text + text;

    // Replace the element text with the new text
    this.page().replaceText(element, valueToType);
};
```

I am using Selenium RC with Java. I have a Java class and I called the `doTypeRepeated` function by following the way:

```
selenium.getEval("doTypeRepeated(\"txtAppCode\", \"service5\")");
```

(`"txtAppCode"` is a textbox and `"service5"` is some text to write/type on the textfield)

I got this error:

```
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: 
    ERROR: Threw an exception: Object expected"
```

Can anyone tell me where am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have switched my test into WebDriver from Selenium RC. executeScript() is replacement of getEval() in Selenium 2 (WebDriver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium mangles the names of extra functions in the Selenium prototype: doFoo becomes simply foo. (Functions starting with is and get are mangled in similar ways.) Try:

```
selenium.getEval("typeRepeated(\"txtAppCode\", \"service5\")");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried by using selenium.getEval("typeRepeated(\"txtAppCode\", \"service5\")");
But I found the following error:

Comment: Sorry, which error? "com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Threw an exception: Object expected"?

Comment: yes, error is:com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Threw an exception: Object expected

Comment: In my application, there are 2 comb box: i) cmbRFARequires and ii) cmbProcureMethod. After selecting a value/option from 1st combo(cmbRFARequires), 2nd combo value/label is loaded which has been done using Ajax. How can i get value/option from 2nd combo by using Selenium RC? Pls help me

Comment: javascript function as Selenium.prototype.doSelect1 = function(locator, optionLocator) {
    var element = this.page().findElement(locator);
    if (!("options" in element)) {
        throw new SeleniumError("Specified element is not a Select (has no options)");
    }
    var locator = this.optionLocatorFactory.fromLocatorString(optionLocator);
    var option = locator.findOption(element);
    this.page().selectOption(element, option);
};

Comment: I called the above javascript function from my java code as:selenium.select("cmbRFARequires", "label=REOI");
  
  
  
  String s[]={"cmbProcureMethod","label=Design Contest"};
  proc.doCommand("select1", s); But i found the following error:com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Option with label 'Design Contest' not found Pls help me